# Godot Engine - AdMob

Tags: admob, godot

I'd like to use ads in my Android mobile game. I set the Android module to:

```
org/godotengine/godot/GodotAdMob
```

In my singleton script I used this code:

```
func _ready():
    if Engine.has_singleton("AdMob"):
        print("success")
    else:
        print("error")
```

Unfortunately, every time I run the app, the console prints "error".

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read through this tutorial? http://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/games/circle_jump/circle_jump_11/#using-godot-modules

Comment: Yes, that's the tutorial I've been following

Comment: If you are still having issues, can you describe what you’ve done so far and also any troubleshooting you’ve done? Otherwise, could you post your solution as an answer and mark it as answered. Thanks!